# Los encabezados no estan alineados

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

Buen dia comunidad, les queria pedir ayudar... tengo un tabla con Ajax, dentro de un modal que me trae datos, pero al momento de abrir el modal y ubicarme en el tab correspondiente que tiene la tabla me la tira de esta manera... los encabezados no se alinean... dejo foto de ref.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adjunto mi código principal de la tabla... la tabla que hice en HTML tiene Width:100% Si no formule bien mi codigo, por favor haganmelo saber, yo comparto lo soliciten para que pueda llegar a una solucion

```
                responsive: true,
                ordering: true,
                scrollCollapse: true,
                scrollY: 530,
                scrollX: true,
                autoWidth: false,
                order: [[0, "desc"]],
                "ajax": {
```

Comment: estas usando alguna libreria como datatable de jquery?

Comment: @David081 si estoy usando y veo que es version 3.6.0

Comment: ¿Qué tal si pones el  `autoWidth: true` y colocas el código completo de la tabla en tu pregunta, no sólo ese pedazo?